# The fastest way to protect/lock an array of ranges on a sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, password-protection

I'm working on a macro that will unprotect an array of ranges under a password on a protected sheet. There are 2 macros, the first one creates an array of ranges to be unprotected, based on several conditions. This part works fine.
However the second part is when I start unprotecting these ranges. The 2nd macro does it in a loop, which is very slow and I don't know of any other way to do that. I know that things go way faster when a given range is contiguous but when I have a series of ranges, what could be the fastest solution?
Here's the code:

```
Sub ResultsRangeProtectionV2(Optional RangeStatus As Boolean = False)

    Dim sh As Worksheet, wsName As Variant, CurrName As Variant, rng As Range, cell As Range, _
    tmp() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, tmpName As String                                    
    
    wsName = Array("Janvier")
    
    ''finding out cells that we want to allow modifying '''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set sh = Worksheets("Janvier")
    Set rng = sh.Range("I7:I" & sh.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).row)
    
    ReDim tmp(1 To rng.Rows.Count + 1)
    j = 1
    
    For i = 0 To rng.Rows.Count
        'If rng(i).HasFormula = True
        If rng(i).Value Like "*sultats*" Or rng(i).HasFormula = True Then
            'Debug.Print rng(i).Address
        Else
            'Debug.Print rng(i).Address
            tmp(j) = rng(i).Address
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    Dim aryLenght As Long
    aryLenght = UBound(tmp) - LBound(tmp) + 1
    Debug.Print "TMP LENGHT IS =" & aryLenght
    
    Dim outputArray() As Variant    
    
    For Each CurrName In wsName
        Set sh = Worksheets(CurrName)
        tmpName = CurrName
        With sh
            .Protect Password:="MDP", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
            .Range("I6:I5000").Locked = Not RangeStatus

            Call CellsLocker(tmp, sh, UBound(outputArray), RangeStatus, tmpName)

        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

And here's the macro that protects ranges in a loop:

```
Sub CellsLocker(ByRef tmp() As Variant, sh As Worksheet, aryLenght As Long, Optional RangeStatus As Boolean = False, Optional CurrName As String = "Janvier")
    
    Dim i As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            
    With sh
        For i = 1 To aryLenght
        If .Range(tmp(i)).MergeCells = False Then
            'Debug.Print "---> " & tmp(i)
            .Range(tmp(i)).Locked = RangeStatus           
        End If
        
        '.Range(tmp(i)).Locked = RangeStatus
        
        Next
    End With

    
ErrorHandler:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I use the entire thing the following way:
`Call ResultsRangeProtectionV2(False)` 
Where "False" stands for unlocking ranges. The same macro can be used to lock ranges as well.

Comment: Looks like you need might need to read up on Excel's Application.Union method.

Comment: My approach to locking-unlocking cells is to leave the cells that users will write unlocked and everything else locked. To activate the lock I protect the sheet. Through VBA I can change the values of the locked cells, in some cases when this is not possible then I unprotect the whole sheet with VBA, make the entries/changes and protect the sheet again. I decide which cells to protect once I build the sheet. Then I protect/unprotect the sheet, not the cells.

Comment: This isn't a different solution as such, however, have you tried switching off screen updating and events when your macro starts, then switching them back on at the end? ... `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` to switch off ... set them both back to True at the end of your macro (including in any error handler if you have one)

Comment: @JohnM Switching on and off these do not help I'm affraid.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ This is exactly what I'm trying to do here in a quick way. But the suer should be able to modify only certain lines in a column. I have too much ranges and sheets for what you've proposed.

Comment: @freeflow This is actually something that can be viable, however I don't have logic behind to elaborate an effective code based on this.

Comment: @OneTwentyTo, Ok, then this code won't be executed while working with the book, but will be executed once when preparing the book. In these cases, since the code will run once, speed is not the critical point, but simplicity so that it can be modified quickly if needed.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ actually the workbook will constantly be used for some quick tasks by a group of users, so it should be quickly operational so I don't have the privilege to impose loading times (we're talking about 5min+ of loading with my code) in this scenario